# How to set a shell script as KDE file association

Tags: kde, opensuse, remote-desktop, plasma5, file-associations

Disclaimer: Cross-posted from SU (which I know is usually discouraged) [*How to set a shell script as KDE file association*](https://superuser.com/q/1828467/516482). Since with only 14 views and no response whatsoever within 3 days I do not have much hope there.

---

I'm connecting to a Win10 with an `*.rdp` file supplied by *Citrix Netscaler Gateway* via download in my FF.

I wrote a shell script that takes the `*.rdp` file as `$1` and it works in *Bash*:

```bash
...
set -x
xfreerdp "$1" /monitors:0,2 /floatbar:sticky:off,default:hidden,show:always /u:<me> /p:<...>
...
```

To be able to run this script from within GUI apps I created a new *File Association* with *Known Type*: *application/rdp* since `*.RPD`, `*.rdp` was assigned to *Remmina* before (and I removed these two from there):

[image: File Association RDP]

There's a `~/.local/share/applications/Bash-RDP.desktop`.

In FF I have set:

[image: FF Settings > Application > RDP]

But, this neither works when opening the downloaded `*.rdp` in FF's downloads drop-down or *Downloads Library* nor in my *Downloads* folder in *Dolphin*. If I do so *xfreerdp* appears in the taskbar with a progress circle for a few seconds only and without any further visual representation. And an *xfreerdp* task remains at every try which I have to kill afterwards.

Comment: Is the shebang line of the script correct?

Comment: @sinabala Can't check it atm but I'm very confident It is – as usual: `#!/bin/bash`. Please also note "_opening the downloaded `*.rdp`_ [...] _xfreerdp appears in the taskbar_". So there _is_ some kind of file association but I'm not sure whether it is to my script.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's why I asked. Could have been that your script calculates the right options for xfreerdp when run in bash, but if run in the default sh, it doesn't. That was, however, just a guess, hence me asking :)

Comment: Maybe you just want to just temporarily modify your script to write the command line as expanded to a file in /tmp , look for oddities. Also, log the output of xfreerdp to your system log, including stderr. `logger` is your friend!

Comment: @sinabala Please see above again: `set -x` shows the expanded cmd and I'm already logging to where the script resides: `~/bin/rdp.log` and `~/bin/rdp.err`. There's nothing that worries me or gives a hint in any of them. I'm going to update the Q with their contents once I have hands on the machine again.

Comment: @sinabala There is an answer on the sister site and it looks promising: https://superuser.com/a/1828888/516482.